# transmitting data to serial port using comm api in java

Tags: java, api, serial-port

I have a serial plotter (MP2300 GRAPHTEC..very old), that I am writing a java program with the Comm API  to communicate with it. I am using XON/XOFF (in the plotter setting) and in my java program.

I know for sure that there is a flow control issue between the computer and the plotter. After a while of plotting, the plotter draws erratic patterns in the middle of the drawing. If I introduce a delay after sending a chunk of the file (I am delaying 1 seconds every 10 commands sent to the plotter), the drawing is perfect.

My question:
Do I have to read data from the plotter to find out if there is a XOFF issued by the device, or that is already taken care for within the API?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a OS driver, then it is already taken care of. The application don't need to worry about.